# Unwanted icon appearing on wpf dialog box after upgrading to VS Pro 2019

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I upgraded to VS pro 2019.  Using code written with VS Pro 2013, a unwanted icon appears at the top of the wpf dialog box (with a light blue background, includes icons plus "Hot Reload available").  Please advise.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-and-disable-edit-and-continue?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

[XAML Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/xaml-hot-reload?view=vs-2019) helps you build your WPF or UWP app user interface (UI) by letting you make changes to XAML code while your app is running. Hot Reload is available in both Visual Studio and Blend for Visual Studio.

If you want to disale the in-app toolbar, then open Debug > Options > General. Make sure that both options, [Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML and Enable XAML Hot Reload are not being selected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/xaml-hot-reload-troubleshooting?view=vs-2019#verify-that-xaml-hot-reload-is-enabled)